# How to decode data from Content Stream

Tags: pdf, itext

I created a pdf document using the code looks like the following:

```
// The text parameter equels 'שדג' it is Hebrew. unicode equivalent is '\u05E9\u05D3\u05D2'
private static void createSimplePdf(String filename, String text) throws Exception {

        final String path = RunItextApp.class.getResource("/Arial.ttf").getPath();
        final PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(path, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

        Style hebrewStyle = new Style()
                .setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
                .setFontSize(14)
                .setFont(font);

        final PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(filename);
        final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        final Document pdf = new Document(pdfDocument);
        pdf.add(
                new Paragraph(text)
                        .setFontScript(Character.UnicodeScript.HEBREW)
                        .addStyle(hebrewStyle)
        );

        pdf.close();
        System.out.println("The document '" + filename + "' has been created.");
    }
```

and after that, I tried to open this document using `pdfbox` util and I got the following data:
[image]
but I got an unexpected result in the `Contents:stream` section especially `Tj` tag. I expected string like the following `05E905D305D2` but I got `02b902a302a2`. I tried to convert this `hex` string to normal string and I got the following result: `ʹʣʢ` but I expected that string `שדג`.
What do I wrong? Hot to convert this `02b902a302a2` string and get `שדג`?

Comment: The numbers you get are not Unicode characters but font indexes instead. (Check how the font is embedded!) The text in a PDF does not specifically care about Unicode – it may or may not be this. Good PDF creators add a `/ToUnicode` table to help decoding, but it's optional.

Comment: why the PDFBox label?

Comment: @usr2564301 thanks for the help! I found ```/ToUnicode``` section.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr because they are using the PDF syntax browser (I don't know the official name) of Pdfbox. Maybe they are not aware that iText also has a PDF syntax browser called RUPS: https://itextpdf.com/en/blog/technical-notes/rups-looking-inside-your-pdfs Based on screenshots alone, I'd say that basic functionality is the same, but RUPS has more features. But I'm biased. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer writes in a comment @usr2564301. Thanks for the help!
The numbers you get are not Unicode characters but font indexes instead. (Check how the font is embedded!) The text in a PDF does not specifically care about Unicode – it may or may not be this. Good PDF creators add a /ToUnicode table to help decoding, but it's optional.

Comment: It would have been nice to mention that usr2564301 originally wrote that in a comment to your question.

Comment: @mkl I agree with you. I tried to find how to add a comment as an answer but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Transforming answers in comments and vice versa is only possible for moderators. One can simply ask the person in another comment to re-post the comment as answer. Or one can create an answer and quote the original content with author reference as you have now.

Comment: My comment pointed out a possible cause (and solution) only. It would be a better answer if you added exactly how you changed your code.